# How to scrape data from a web site?

Tags: r, web-scraping, dataframe

I am using the following code to get information from a web site (http://q.stock.sohu.com/cn/000002/lshq.shtml). But I do not know how to get a data frame which includes "date,open,close,high,low". Any help would be appreciated.

```
thepage = readLines('http://q.stock.sohu.com/hisHq?code=cn_000002&start=20131120&end=20140318&stat=1&order=D&period=d&callback=historySearchHandler&rt=jsonp&r=0.8740235545448934&0.28161772061461654')
```

How can I get the data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which parts of the return JSON are the actual values you need, but I assume they are components of the `hq` record. This should work:

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)

# get the raw data
dat.json.raw <- getURL("http://q.stock.sohu.com/hisHq?code=cn_000002&start=20131120&end=20140318&stat=1&order=D&period=d&callback=historySearchHandler&rt=jsonp&r=0.8740235545448934&0.28161772061461654%27")
tt <- textConnection(dat.json.raw)
dat.json <- readLines(tt)
close(tt)

# remove callback
dat.json <- gsub("^historySearchHandler\\(", "", dat.json)
dat.json <- gsub("\\)$", "", dat.json)

# convert to R structure
dat.l <- fromJSON(dat.json)

# get the meaty part of the data into a data.frame
dat <- data.frame(t(sapply(dat.l[[1]]$hq, unlist)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat$X1 <- as.Date(dat$X1)
dat$X2 <- as.numeric(dat$X2)
dat$X3 <- as.numeric(dat$X3)
dat$X4 <- as.numeric(dat$X4)

str(dat)
## 'data.frame':    79 obs. of  10 variables:
##  $ X1 : Date, format: "2014-03-18" "2014-03-17" "2014-03-14" ...
##  $ X2 : num  7.76 7.6 7.68 7.58 7.48 7.19 7.22 7.34 6.76 6.92 ...
##  $ X3 : num  7.6 7.76 7.53 7.71 7.6 7.5 7.15 7.27 7.32 6.76 ...
##  $ X4 : num  -0.16 0.23 -0.18 0.11 0.1 0.35 -0.12 -0.05 0.56 -0.16 ...
##  $ X5 : chr  "-2.06%" "3.05%" "-2.33%" "1.45%" ...
##  $ X6 : chr  "7.55" "7.59" "7.50" "7.53" ...
##  $ X7 : chr  "7.76" "7.80" "7.81" "7.85" ...
##  $ X8 : chr  "843900" "1177079" "1303110" "1492359" ...
##  $ X9 : chr  "64268.06" "90829.30" "99621.34" "114990.40" ...
##  $ X10: chr  "0.87%" "1.22%" "1.35%" "1.54%" ...

head(dat)
##           X1   X2   X3    X4     X5   X6   X7      X8        X9   X10
## 1 2014-03-18 7.76 7.60 -0.16 -2.06% 7.55 7.76  843900  64268.06 0.87%
## 2 2014-03-17 7.60 7.76  0.23  3.05% 7.59 7.80 1177079  90829.30 1.22%
## 3 2014-03-14 7.68 7.53 -0.18 -2.33% 7.50 7.81 1303110  99621.34 1.35%
## 4 2014-03-13 7.58 7.71  0.11  1.45% 7.53 7.85 1492359 114990.40 1.54%
## 5 2014-03-12 7.48 7.60  0.10  1.33% 7.42 7.85 2089873 160315.88 2.16%
## 6 2014-03-11 7.19 7.50  0.35  4.90% 7.15 7.59 1892488 141250.94 1.96%
```

You'll need to fix some of the other columns (since I don't know exactly what you need).

For folks who don't like the warnings that come back from the `fromJSON` call, you can just wrap the `readLines` with a `paste` : `dat.json <- paste(readLines(tt), collapse="")`. It's not necessary (the warnings are harmless) so I don't usually bother with the extra step.

Comment: Hopefully the callback function name doesn't change. You can tweak the first `gsub()` if so (I guess it can also be made a bit more generic if need be). Getting stuff out of JSON is often challenging and this particular pattern works well for me (with tweaks) most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to scrape a website that presents the data in [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

For that, in addition to the "usual steps" that you need to do in order to scrape a website you'll also need to deal with parsing and manipulating JSON data:

### Usual approach

If you have a HTML that has an easy to grab table, this should work:

```
require("XML")
x <- readHTMLTable(
    doc="swww.someurl.com"
)
```

Otherwise you'll definitely need to use some [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) to get to the nodes that you're interested in.

This usually involves parsing the HTML code via `htmlTreeParse()` and getting to the respective nodes via `getNodeSet()` and the like:

```
x <- htmlTreeParse(
    file="swww.someurl.com",
    isURL=TRUE,
    useInternalNodes=TRUE
)

res <- getNodeSet(x, <your-xpath-statement>)
```

### Approach including JSON data

Parse the HTML code:

```
x <- htmlTreeParse(
    file="http://q.stock.sohu.com/hisHq?code=cn_000002&start=20131120&end=20140318&stat=1&order=D&period=d&callback=historySearchHandler&rt=jsonp&r=0.8740235545448934&0.28161772061461654",
    isURL=TRUE,
    useInternalNodes=TRUE
)
```

Retrieve the actual JSON data:

```
json <- getNodeSet(x, "//body/p")
json <- xmlValue(json[[1]])
```

Get rid of non-JSON components:

```
json <- gsub("historySearchHandler\\(", "", json, perl=TRUE)
json <- gsub("\\)$", "", json, perl=TRUE)
```

Parse the JSON data:

```
require("jsonlite")
fromJSON(json, simplifyVector=FALSE)

[[1]]
[[1]]$status
[1] 0

[[1]]$hq
[[1]]$hq[[1]]
[[1]]$hq[[1]][[1]]
[1] "2014-03-18"

[[1]]$hq[[1]][[2]]
[1] "7.76"

[...]
```

Now you need to bring that into a more `data.frame`-like order (methods that come to mind are `do.call()`, `rbind()`, `cbind`).

### Encoding

Sooner or later (rather sooner than later as we see in this very example), you'll be confronted with encoding issues (stuff like `"Ã€Ã›Â¼Ã†:"`).

You can play around with different encodings either directly when parsing the HTML code (argument `encoding` in `htmlTreeParse()`) or modify a character string's encoding via `Encoding` "afterwards". I wasn't able to get it all correct for your values, though. Encoding issues can be quite a pain.

### General suggestion

I'd recommend you to choose english-based examples (an english-based website in this case) in the future as otherwise you're tremendously limiting the amount of people that might be able to help you.

Comment: all your suggestions are grateful. i have not fund a proper english-based example. Just if i have got the data of "thepage". how can i convert the data into a data frame which just include: 2014-03-18,"2014-03-18","7.76","7.60","-0.16","-2.06%","7.55","7.76","843900","64268.06","0.87%"

Comment: Well, by the workflow that I outlined. If you try to work directly on `thepage` as returned by `readLines()` (which is plain text, not a parsed object), you won't get very far and/or need to use a vast amount of regular expressions. What you want is to work with the **parsed** HTML code as it allows you to easily navigate within the node tree. If you want to webscrape, you need to learn some XPath and/or JSON, sorry.

Comment: thepage<-("historySearchHandler([{"status":0,"hq":[["2014-03-18","7.76","7.60","-0.16","-2.06%","7.55","7.76","843900","64268.06","0.87%"],["2014-03-17","7.60","7.76","0.23","3.05%","7.59","7.80","1177079","90829.30","1.22%"],["2014-03-14","7.68","7.53","-0.18","-2.33%","7.50","7.81","1303110","99621.34","1.35%"],["2014-03-13","7.58","7.71","0.11","1.45%","7.53","7.85","1492359","114990.40","1.54%"],],"code":"cn_000002","stat":["total:","2013-11-20 to 2014-03-18","-1.48","-16.30%",6.52,9.18,67132727,5123460.72,"69.4%"]}])"